# "songs" package, author font

Tags: formatting, songs

I'm creating my own songbook with `songs` package.
I would like to customize font of song author beneath song title.
I searched the documentation and only found option to change song title font (`\stitlefont`) but not song author (or any other Beginsong Keyvals).

### I would like to enlarge author name in my example "Plavi Orkestar".

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[chorded]{songs}
\usepackage[slovene]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

%index
\newindex{titleidx}{cbtitle}
\newauthorindex{authidx}{cbauth}

%% Page Layout %%
    \usepackage[top=25mm, bottom=25mm, left=21mm, right=21mm]{geometry}
    \pagestyle{plain}%pokaže samo številke strani
    \pagenumbering{arabic}%številčenje z arabskimi številkami

%% Fonts %%
    \usepackage[default,osfigures,scale=0.95]{opensans}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%lyrics font
    \renewcommand{\lyricfont}{\scshape\normalsize} %Smallcaps
%song title font
    %\renewcommand{\stitlefont}{\rmfont\Large}
%Chorus font
    \renewcommand{\chorusfont}{\slshape\scshape\mdseries\normalsize} 
%chords font
    \renewcommand\printchord[1]{\normalfont\slshape\normalsize#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{songs}{titleidx,authidx}
\beginsong{Ako su to samo bile laži}[
  by={Plavi\ orkestar}]
\beginverse*
\[D]Život ide dalje, život brzo prol\[Em]azi,
a osjećam da to više ni\[D]si ti, a\[A] ni ja. 
\[D]Moža bi i mogli pokušti pono\[Em]vo,
al bojim se da ovaj je p\[D]ut goto\[A]vo. 
\endverse
\beginchorus
Al' samo \[Em]ti mi ubrzavaš disanje\[A], 
jer\[Em] ja se jošuvijek palim na \[A]tebe. 
\[D]Ako su to samo bi\[A]le laž, 
lažmo se bar jošmalo, 
\[D]ako su to samo bi\[A]le varke, 
varajmo se, varaj\[D]mo.
\endchorus
\beginverse*\chordsoff
Život ide, život brzo prolazi, 
a osječam da to viš nisi ti, a ni ja. 
Ljubavi i mržje, teško je preskočiti zid, 
al' se bojim da dobar smo par bili mi.
\chordson
\endverse 
\endsong
\end{songs}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Hello! Perhaps redefining `\showauthors`? Here's a way: `\makeatletter\renewcommand\showauthors{\setbox\SB@box\hbox{\itshape\sfcode\`.\@m\songauthors}\ifdim\wd\SB@box>\z@\unhbox\SB@box\par\fi}\makeatother` (the original code uses `\bfseries`, I replaced it by `\itshape`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The song authors are typeset in bold due to the macro `\showauthors` which contains `\bfseries` (as  already pointed out by Paulo Cereda) as well as in a fontsize smaller than `\scriptsize`. I suggest to change the formatting and fontsize by adding, e.g., the following to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\showauthors}{\bfseries}{\itshape\normalsize}{}{}
```